# Shortest string possible

Tags: grammar, theory

I was at an interview, and I was asked to give the shortest string generated given this context free grammar. I did not review in years, so I think I got it wrong. What is the answer so I know it for future purposes?

```
S --> ABA | SS
A --> S0  | T1T
B --> S1  | 0
T --> 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By inspection, the shortest string in this language is derived as follows:

```
S
=> ABA      // SS can only be worse than S, no reason to take that route
=> T1TBT1T  // S0 can only be worse than T1T, since S0 will necessarily add more A
=> 0100010  // choosing a single terminal is always as good as we can do
```

This shows you how to think about manual inspection. An algorithmic solution is a separate question and, frankly, not what it sounds like you were asked to do.